# Regex to find a particular word

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have an HTML file and I want to find a particular URL inside it.

1. Starting with `http://abcd.com/Admin/CoreFolder/Resources/`
2. Has a JPG file. Ex - `http://abcd.com/Admin/CoreFolder/Resources/ff8127aa-bf81-4833-ba12-edf2f366ccbb.jpg`

Can you help me out with the regex for the same. I want to find all occurrences and replace the `abcd.com` with `xyz.com`.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a text file which contains URLs? "a html" is not a very clear description of your object...

Comment: What language do you use? For the regex it is about the same but for the replacing it matters. I guess you want to use javascript in a client's browser but it is not clear.

Comment: I want to use it in asp.net application

Comment: @Johnride: There is many differences in regex implementation between languages.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, there are differences, yes. But the scheme is very alike for the languages I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.*?(abcd\.com)[^\s]*?\.jpg`

**DEMO** : http://regexr.com?3853l

Then you can replace the first capture ( the part within braces ) with xyz.com

Comment: @Floris Thanks. Corrected to a better version.

Answer (score 1):

This is a RegEx that will match any .jpg link starting with http://abcd.com/Admin/CoreFolder/Resources/

```
(http://abcd.com/Admin/CoreFolder/Resources/(.+?).jpg)
```

[Example test on RegExr](http://regexr.com?3853i)

Answer (score 0):

Using something like `sed` to do the search and replace (you didn't actually give enough information about your environment - like "what language do you want to implement your regex in"?):

```
sed 's/\(http:\/\/\)\(abcd\.com\\)\(/Admin\/CoreFolder\/Resources\/.*\.jpg\)/\1xyz\.com\2/' myFile.html > newFile.html
```